# How to run my function in enter key press on Google docs

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, google-docs

I would like to know how to run my Google.script function when I hit enter key on Google Docs. My aim is to copy the current paragraph and paste it into MS Word. I think I know how to get the text from Google Docs but I don't know how to run my Google Apps Script function on enter key press. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a trigger to run a script on enter key press. The available triggers are listed on the following docs:

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable