# How do get custom functions to recalculate in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I created a custom function for google spreadsheets. All it does is return a random letter. The function works great when I first enter it into a cell. But now I want to be able to "recalculate" the function using a keyboard shortcut; I'd also be willing to refresh the page if needed.

TLDR: I want to be able to hit a key and have my custom functions recalculate.

How can I accomplish this?

Edit to add:
Here is the code for my function.

```
//returns a random letter suitable for use in function notation
function ranFunLet() {
  var letters = ['a','b','c','d','f','g','h','j','k','m','n','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
  var letter = letters[Math.floor(Math.random()*letters.length)];
  //console.log(letter);
  return letter;
}
```

I would like the cell I use it in to run the function again when I press a button (or refresh the page).

Comment: you would need to use onEdit trigger or bind your script to button. tho if you want just random letter on deman there are few non-scripted solutions if you are interested

Comment: I tried onEdit in triggers, but nothing happened. I'll try to look up the code for the button binding. (I prefer the scripted solution because I'm planning to use this function on a few different spreadsheets.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Suggestion

The Apps Script editor does support keyboard shortcut trigger as per [this existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53530030/15384825). However, you may want to try [Importing functions as macros](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/macros#importing_functions_as_macros), then you can assign a unique keyboard shortcut to it.

### Here's a sample

**Sample Sheet**

[image]

**Sample script function to test**

> This sample script function increments the number on `A1` cell.

```
function sample() {
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet().getRange("A1").getValue();
  var res = data+1;
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet().getRange("A1").setValue(res);
}
```

**Import the function on your spreadsheet (in my testing it is named as `sample`)**:

1. In the Google Sheets UI, select **Tools** > **Macros** > **Import**.
2. Select a **function** form the list presented and then click **Add
   function**.
3. Select **clear** to close the dialog.
4. Select **Tools** > **Macros** > **Manage macros**.
5. Locate the function you just imported in the list. Assign a unique
   keyboard shortcut to the macro. You can also change the macro name
   here; the name defaults to the name of the function.

> [image]

6. Click **Update** to save the macro configuration.

### Result

> After pressing the sample shortcut key `Ctrl + Alt + Shift + 2`, the function incremented the number on `A1` cell from `1` to `2`:

[image]

> **NOTE**: *You can not choose a specific shortcut & if you'll edit your function on the Apps Script editor, you would need to re-import your function again as a macro.*

Comment: This doesn't quite work. I'm adding the code to my original post. It's pretty straightforward.

All I want is for the cell to run the function again when I hit a key (or refresh the page).

Comment: PS - The reason I don't want to have the code actually "choose" which cells to populate is because I'd like to be able to use this code again on other Spreadsheets. Therefore, I don't want to commit to a specific cell being manipulated within the function definition. I'd rather use a simple function, and then use `=randFunLet()` in whatever cells I choose. But I would need them to "recalculate" on demand for them to be useful for me.

Comment: I see. So it has to directly manipulate the specific cell from the function. That's a shame. I really wanted to use it as a time saver for generating random letters whenever I need them in any old spreadsheet.

Comment: Hmmm... if that is the case, the only workaround that I can think of that's close is by using this method: `function ranFunLet(){ 
  var letters = ['a','b','c','d','f','g','h','j','k','m','n','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'] 
  var letter = letters[Math.floor(Math.random()*letters.length)];
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveRange().setValue(letter);
} `. This line `SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveRange().setValue(letter);` will post the `letter` value on any cell you select on your sheet, given you've already add the function as macro & a keyboard shortcut to it.

Comment: @GMath314 got it. Right, this is just a workaround as there's no direct way of triggering to refresh a custom function via a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I figured an alternative workaround that combined both proposed solutions from this post. Basically, I made a helper function called toSheet() which populates the cells using the output from my original function. Then I linked it to a button. I really appreciate your time on it. ( Also credited @player0 )

Answer (score 1):

the button solution is done like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yaBMsSpAxYM**